# what is causing this endforeach error when I try to upgrade the site to PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, web

Hey This code of mine is causing a total crash on my website:

```
<select size="1" class="<?php echo $this->level; ?> mobilenav" onchange="document.location.href = '/'+this.value">

<?
if(/*$this->level == "level_1"*/ false) {
?>
    <option value="">Navigation...</option>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item): 
  
    $classes = explode(" ",$item["class"]); 

    ?>

      <optgroup label="<?= $item["link"] ?>">
          <?= $item["subitems"] ?>
      </optgroup>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?
} else {
    foreach ($this->items as $item):

        $classes = explode(" ",$item["class"]);

        ?>
        <?php if ($item['isActive'] || in_array("trail",$classes)): ?>
        <option class="<?php echo $item['class']; ?>" selected="selected"><span class="<?php echo $item['class']; ?>"><?php echo $item['link']; ?></span></option>
    <?php else: ?>
        <option<?php if ($item['class']): ?> class="<?php echo $item['class']; ?>"<?php endif; ?> value="<?php echo $item['href']; ?>"><?php echo $item['link']; ?></option>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach;
}?>
</select>
```

Story: im Upgrading an old Website of mine currently to be able to use it with the newest version of PHP.

This is the error im getting:

```
[2021-07-27 08:08:38] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception ParseError: "syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH), expecting end of file" at /var/www/vhosts/web/templates/nav_dropdown.html5 line 20 {"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH), expecting end of file at /var/www/vhosts/web/templates/nav_dropdown.html5:20)"} []
```

I dont get why it is expecting the code to end at line 20, maybe someone has a fast answer for me?
thanks in advance.
Hans.

Comment: Has that syntax ever been correct though? I would expect `<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: @Sam020 As opposed to what? The following `}` is separate, closing the else block.

Comment: In php7.4 u can't use `<?` u need to write `<?php`

Comment: @IMSoP sorry, kinda new to this syntax. But I see 2 different kinds of syntax for the foreach-loop in the example and to me the second foreach looks not closed. But apparently I'm wrong :)

Comment: @Sam020 "endforeach;" can go anywhere any other PHP code can go. `<php foreach($a as $b): echo $b; endforeach; echo "done"; ?>` would be perfectly valid.

Comment: @RudyDavid That is not true. The short_open tag setting is still available, and does exactly the same thing it did in previous versions.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the error is not from the *version* of PHP, but the *configuration*: you have the [short_open_tag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) setting turned off on your new server/installation.

Since you have a mixture of short (`<?`) and full (`<?php`) tags here, if short tags is off, PHP will only be reading half of them. To PHP, the `if`, `else`, and second `foreach` simply don't exist (they'll be part of the output), so it's as though you'd written this:

```
<select size="1" class="<?php echo $this->level; ?> mobilenav" onchange="document.location.href = '/'+this.value">

    <option value="">Navigation...</option>
<?php foreach ($this->items as $item): 
  
    $classes = explode(" ",$item["class"]); 

    ?>

      <optgroup label="<?= $item["link"] ?>">
          <?= $item["subitems"] ?>
      </optgroup>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ($item['isActive'] || in_array("trail",$classes)): ?>
        <option class="<?php echo $item['class']; ?>" selected="selected"><span class="<?php echo $item['class']; ?>"><?php echo $item['link']; ?></span></option>
    <?php else: ?>
        <option<?php if ($item['class']): ?> class="<?php echo $item['class']; ?>"<?php endif; ?> value="<?php echo $item['href']; ?>"><?php echo $item['link']; ?></option>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach;
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with your code but it was still having some issues so I just went on Plesk and turned the Short_open_tag on. All working fine now :-) Thanks again!

Comment: @hansmans Well, that will teach you to read more carefully before copy and pasting code: I didn't say you _should_ be using the above code; I said this was what your current code _looked like to PHP_. If the setting solved the problem, feel free to "accept" this answer (with the tick mark next to the score) so that the question is marked as "resolved".